# Python: Input and output filename matching

Tags: python, filenames, matching

I'm trying to come up with a way for the filenames that I'm reading to have the same filename as what I'm writing. The code is currently reading the images and doing some processing. My output will be extracting the data from that process into a csv file. I want both the filenames to be the same. I've come across fname for matching, but that's for existing files.

Comment: search rename files python

Comment: @PyNEwbie rename files is only for renaming existing files. i'm only trying to get the input file to match the output file.

Answer (score 1):

So if your input file name is in_file = myfile.jpg do this:

```
my_outfile = "".join(infile.split('.')[:-1]) + 'csv'
```

This splits infile into a list of parts that are separated by '.'.  It then puts them back together minus the last part, and adds csv

your my_outfile will be `myfile.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Well in python it's possible to do that but, the original file might be corrupted if we were to have the same exact file name i.e `BibleKJV.pdf` to path `BibleKJV.pdf` will corrupt the first file. Take a look at this script to verify that I'm on the right track (if I'm totally of disregard my answer):

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader , PdfFileWriter

path = "C:/Users/Catrell Washington/Pride"

input_file_name = os.path.join(path, "BibleKJV.pdf")
input_file = PdfFileReader(open(input_file_name , "rb"))

output_PDF = PdfFileWriter()

total_pages = input_file.getNumPages()

for page_num in range(1,total_pages) :
     output_PDF.addPage(input_file.getPage(page_num))

output_file_name = os.path.join(path, "BibleKJV.pdf")
output_file = open(output_file_name , "wb")
output_PDF.write(output_file)

output_file.close()
```

When I ran the above script, I lost all data from the original path `"BibleKJV.pdf"` thus proving that if the file name and the file delegation i.e .pdf .cs .word etc, are the same then the data, unless changed very minimal, will be corrupted.

If this doesn't give you any help please, edit your question with a script of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: well, in your script, they both have the same extension. i also forgot to mention that i'm writing to a different directory as well. does writing to the same directory corrupt the file as well?

Comment: The only way the file will be corrupted, if written to the same directory, is if there's a mishap in your code where you change almost all of the original file. Just like in my script.